# The verb used to mean the action of blowing air with your mouth because you are bored, annoyed etc?

Tags: word-request

What is the verb used to mean the action of blowing air with your mouth because you are bored,annoyed etc? I couldn't find it on the internet. I need you guys' help. We call that sound made, "Üfff...," in my language. It sounds like "ffff." I don't think it is exactly a "sigh."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say they '*let out a [huff](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/huff)*'.

A 'huff' is a sharp exhalation of air. It can also be a verb '*to huff*'.

It can be used in contexts other than expressions of annoyance, for example, if someone is out of breath due to exercise ("*we were huffing and puffing by the time we'd climbed to the top of the hill*").

When someone 'huffs' in connection with speech it indicates indignance, for example:

> "Certainly not!" he huffed.

Even without associated speech, in a context where it is a reaction to something said or done, saying "*he huffed*" or "*he let out a huff*" would aptly describe an expression of indignance.

For contexts where it is less about annoyance and more boredom, you might consider saying they gave (or let out) "*a heavy sigh*"?